# What happens when a synchronized method is called by a thread via another class?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Feels good to be a part of this community. Have read lot of answers clearing my doubts for many ques but didn't find one for this one. I know how the synchronization works in Java, but confused to see a deviated behavior when the synchronized method is being called by the the threads via another class.

PSB what I tried:

Class A with synchronzed method "meth1".

```
package threadinterview;

public class A {
public synchronized void meth1()
{
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("meth1: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Class B with non-synhronized method "meth2"

```
package threadinterview;

public class B {
public void meth2() {
    A a1 = new A();
    a1.meth1();
}
}
```

Main class to run the project

```
package threadinterview;
public class ThreadImpl {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final B b1 = new B();
    final B b2 = new B();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            b1.meth2();
        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            b1.meth2();
        }
    }).start();
}
}
```

Now in this scenario, even though I am ultimately running the synchronized method, I can't see the effect of synchronization. Here what I get when I run the program:

```
meth1: Thread-0
meth1: Thread-1
meth1: Thread-0
meth1: Thread-1
meth1: Thread-0
meth1: Thread-1
```

And if I make the synchronized method static as well, then I get the class level lock and can see the synchronization effect in place. I seriously don't understand why the class level locking works but the object level doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each call to

```
public void meth2() {
    A a1 = new A();
    a1.meth1();
}
```

creates a new `A` object. `synchronized` on the method synchronizes on `this`, the object itself. Therefore, you are synchronizing on different objects. One synchronized call doesn't prevent the other synchronized call as both threads get different monitors.

Comment: Got it. Wasn't tough, but didn't click. Thanks a ton. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding what the 'synchronization effect' is. In your example, you are calling `B.meth2()` from two separate threads. This method creates a new instance of class `A` and then calls `A.meth1()`. Now whatever locking you are trying to enforce on `meth1()` (which is not really clear from your example or description), it's irrelevant because you are calling it on two different instances of class `A`, i.e., you are implicitly using two different locks.